# Juju and the Openstack provider with an external objectstore service (or without it)

Tags: juju, openstack, cloud

I'm trying to use Juju with the Openstack provider, but it seems I've hit a roadblock. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and Juju 1.24.

I'm trying to use a private Openstack cluster, but it doesn't have integrated any objectstore service (neither Swift or nova-objectstore).

Would it be possible to use that Openstack cluster with an external objectstore provider, for example AWS S3?

It would also be OK to use it without the objectstore, but as far as I've read in the documentation, the Openstack provider is still depending on it.

Any help will be really appreciated :)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently a limitation of Juju on OpenStack:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1456265

We are hoping to enable Juju without an object store in Juju 1.25, should be in beta in a week or so, but definitely one of the things we hope to fix soon!